# Unable to access the constructor string in execute method in Batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, debugging

i am getting the string in constructor. but how can i access that string in execute method. i am trying to access like this:

```
global class samplebatchcreateaccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private String strParameter;

    public batchAccountInsert(String strParam) {
        strParameter = strParam;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'select id,Name from Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
         System.debug('The string is'+strParameter); List<codeslist> lstcodeMapping = (List<codeslist>)JSON.deserialize(strParameter, List<codeslist>.class); system.debug('after deserializing'+lstcodeMapping);
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

But I am unable to see the debug logs for the execute method. And here is my debuglogs:

41.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
05:26:27.0 (285390)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0056A000000Sl39|mallikarjuna.reddy@omuat.com|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-08:00
05:26:27.0 (326962)|EXECUTION_STARTED
05:26:27.0 (331392)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p6A000006aLk7|codeexport
05:26:27.0 (108152368)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
05:26:27.0 (108211072)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
05:26:27.0 (108227794)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
05:26:27.0 (108239195)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
05:26:27.0 (108249275)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
05:26:27.0 (108276314)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
05:26:27.0 (108933539)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:1565418
05:26:27.0 (109075746)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:11
05:26:27.0 (109090285)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[15]|BatchableContextImpl.BatchableContextImpl()
05:26:27.0 (109096134)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
05:26:27.0 (109104417)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[15]|BatchableContextImpl
05:26:27.0 (109111550)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
05:26:27.0 (109115980)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
05:26:27.0 (109122279)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[31]|this|Database.BatchableContextImpl|true|false
05:26:27.0 (109169772)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[31]|this|{}|0x4d8b5242
05:26:27.0 (109176251)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[31]|jobId|Id|false|false
05:26:27.0 (109251254)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[31]|jobId|"7076A00000pFcWUQA0"
05:26:27.0 (109257177)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[31]|childJobId|Id|false|false
05:26:27.0 (109265306)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[31]|childJobId|null
05:26:27.0 (119993430)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:19
05:26:27.0 (120009426)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:75
05:26:27.0 (120013741)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:11
05:26:27.0 (120017076)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:44
05:26:27.0 (120028682)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p6A000006aLk7|codeexport.codeexport()
05:26:27.0 (120035995)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
05:26:27.0 (120042090)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
05:26:27.0 (120043412)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
05:26:27.0 (120044547)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[18]
05:26:27.0 (120052170)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|codeexport
05:26:27.0 (120060468)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
05:26:27.0 (120065304)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
05:26:27.0 (120072239)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[98]|this|codeexport|true|false
05:26:27.0 (120120742)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[98]|this|{"ma":"[{\"slabel\":\"US:\",\"sc (1565390 more) ..."}|0x17285897
05:26:27.0 (120127287)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[98]|BC|Database.BatchableContext|true|false
05:26:27.0 (120195694)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[98]|BC|{"jobId":"7076A00000pFcWUQA0"}|0x4d8b5242
05:26:27.0 (120208876)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[98]
05:26:27.128 (128190671)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
05:26:27.128 (128190671)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 200
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 60000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 12000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 0
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 0
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 1
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

05:26:27.128 (128190671)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

05:26:27.0 (128232648)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|codeexport
05:26:27.0 (128977142)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

And the second debug is:

41.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
05:26:26.0 (334989)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0056A000000Sl39|mallikarjuna.reddy@omuat.com|Pacific Standard Time|GMT-08:00
05:26:26.0 (370096)|EXECUTION_STARTED
05:26:26.0 (374815)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p6A000006aLk7|codeexport
05:26:26.0 (107610321)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[72]|Bytes:3
05:26:26.0 (107676240)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[77]|Bytes:152
05:26:26.0 (107694540)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[342]|Bytes:408
05:26:26.0 (107710500)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[355]|Bytes:408
05:26:26.0 (107723397)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[467]|Bytes:48
05:26:26.0 (107752433)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6
05:26:26.0 (108475704)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:1565418
05:26:26.0 (129215419)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:11
05:26:26.0 (129238156)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[15]|BatchableContextImpl.BatchableContextImpl()
05:26:26.0 (129243407)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[15]
05:26:26.0 (129254374)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[15]|BatchableContextImpl
05:26:26.0 (129260964)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
05:26:26.0 (129264931)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:4
05:26:26.0 (129270355)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[31]|this|Database.BatchableContextImpl|true|false
05:26:26.0 (129314843)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[31]|this|{}|0x179637a5
05:26:26.0 (129320768)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[31]|jobId|Id|false|false
05:26:26.0 (129395547)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[31]|jobId|"7076A00000pFcWUQA0"
05:26:26.0 (129401938)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[31]|childJobId|Id|false|false
05:26:26.0 (129409754)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[31]|childJobId|null
05:26:26.0 (129732021)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:19
05:26:26.0 (129741504)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:75
05:26:26.0 (129745382)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:11
05:26:26.0 (129748483)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:44
05:26:26.0 (129755430)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p6A000006aLk7|codeexport.codeexport()
05:26:26.0 (129760541)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
05:26:26.0 (129764180)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[1]
05:26:26.0 (129765412)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[3]
05:26:26.0 (129766749)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[18]
05:26:26.0 (129770457)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|codeexport
05:26:26.0 (129775458)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:8
05:26:26.0 (129778453)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
05:26:26.0 (129783100)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[37]|this|codeexport|true|false
05:26:26.0 (129808579)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[37]|this|{"ma":"[{\"slabel\":\"US:\",\"sc (1565390 more) ..."}|0x3ced7b5e
05:26:26.0 (129815067)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[37]|BC|Database.BatchableContext|true|false
05:26:26.0 (129860355)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[37]|BC|{"jobId":"7076A00000pFcWUQA0"}|0x179637a5
05:26:26.0 (129870534)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[37]
05:26:26.0 (129872163)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[39]
05:26:26.0 (129875764)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[39]|Bytes:48
05:26:26.0 (129881692)|VARIABLE_SCOPE_BEGIN|[39]|query|String|false|false
05:26:26.0 (129892014)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[39]|query|"select id, name from (28 more) ..."
05:26:26.0 (129895792)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[40]
05:26:26.0 (129897834)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:18
05:26:26.0 (130795615)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[40]|Bytes:1565428
05:26:26.0 (130820062)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5
05:26:26.0 (130836924)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5
05:26:26.0 (130844181)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7
05:26:26.0 (130894104)|USER_DEBUG|[40]|DEBUG|initialState222 is[{"slabel":"US:","scode":"SF.BW1","qlabel":"BW1-BW1","lxkey":"rdm/lookupTypes/LKUP_IMS_BRICK_TYPE_BW1_US","ltname":"rdm/lookupTypes/LKUP_IMS_BRICK_TYPE","lpcode":"BW1","dtlabel":"US:","dtcode":"BW1","concode":"US","codestrans":[{"traexkey":"rdm/lookupTypes/LKUP_IMS_BRICK_TYPE_BW1_en-us_US","mdmltype":"a0Z6A000001xysbUAA","label":"BW1","isolcode":"en-us"},{"traexkey":"rdm/lookupTypes/LKUP_IMS_BRICK_TYPE_BW1_en_US","mdmltype":"a0Z6A000001xysbUAA","label":"BW1","isolcode":"en"}]}
05:26:26.0 (155354960)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[41]
05:26:26.0 (156676593)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[41]|Aggregations:0|select id, name from QIDC__MDM_LookupType_ims__c
05:26:26.0 (160336995)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[41]|Rows:0
05:26:26.260 (260164083)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
05:26:26.260 (260164083)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 200
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 60000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 12000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 0
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 0
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 1
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

05:26:26.260 (260164083)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

05:26:26.0 (260227893)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|codeexport
05:26:26.0 (260981941)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `execute` invocation gets its own log. If you are looking in the same log as that in which you kick off your batch, you're not going to find what you're looking for.